# How do you define an IPv6 /64 block in Apache virtual host

Tags: apache-2.4, ipv6

I tried every combination but I keep getting error restarting Apache. Does anyone knows how to define a block inside apache virtualhost?

```
<VirtualHost "[2601:9ab4:48af:97::/64]:80" _default_:*>
<VirtualHost [2601:9ab4:48af:97::/64]:80 _default_:*>
<VirtualHost [::/64]:80 _default_:*>
<VirtualHost [::]/64:80 _default_:*>
<VirtualHost [*:/64]:80 _default_:*>
```

Comment: A bit more elaboration on why you are trying to do that would improve this question.

Comment: Do you really want your host to be listening on 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 IP addresses? A VirtualHost is defined in the apache documentation as listening on one address.

Comment: To catch all the IPv6 address not defined in virtual host.

Comment: "_To catch all the IPv6 address not defined in virtual host._" Do you do that with IPv4? Host addressing really works the same way for IPv6 as it does for IPv4.

Comment: @SaudIqbal Again, you want your host to listen on `18 quintillion` addresses simultaneously? Is that what you mean by catching the addresses?

Comment: There is at least one other address in that network that does not belong to the host, and that is the gateway address. If the host also claims the gateway address for the network, it will never be able to send packets off the network because it cannot contact the router. I seriously doubt that your host claims every address for an IPv4 network, so why would it want to do that for an IPv6 network?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; you can't use CIDR notation or IP-address ranges in VirtualHost directives.

---

Apache is configured to respond to requests on either :

- a single specific IP-address and port number with the [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directive
  Either an IPv6 addresss

  ```
  Listen [2601:9ab4:48af:97::1]:80
  ```

  or an IPv4 address

  ```
  Listen 127.0.0.1:80
  ```
- multiple specific IP-addresses and port numbers by adding multiple [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) directives, one for each unique ip-address and port number

  ```
  Listen [2601:9ab4:48af:97::1]:80
  Listen [2601:9ab4:48af:97::2]:80
  Listen [2601:9ab4:48af:97::3]:80
  Listen 127.0.0.1:80
  Listen 127.0.0.2:81
  ```
- every IP-address configured on the host by only setting the port number:

  ```
  Listen 80
  Listen 443
  ```

As far as I know you can't use a netmask or define a range of ip-addresses in the Listen directive.

After apache httpd is configured accept incoming connections by the above Listen directive(s) you can *optionally* create VirtualHost entries.

You can then create [IP based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html) (where you are again restricted to a specific IP-address), [name based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) where the `Host:` header with a DNS domainname in http request headers will by handled by the VirtualHost with that hostname or hostname pattern in  the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`directive and a **default VirtualHost** (typically the first VirtualHost entry) that handles all request that don't match a more specific IP based or Name Based VirtualHost. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you should listen to the commenters and limit your virtual host to one IP address.  Even if you want to try to listen to more than one, maybe try getting one working first.

Second, I do not think you need the quotes around the IP address.

Third, have you tried any of those without the "/64" CIDR notation? Using the second line as an example:

```
<VirtualHost [2601:9ab4:48af:97::]:80>
```

I don't see anything about CIDR notation in the Apache docs here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost

Comment: I tried it but its not catching anything

Comment: What you would need to do here is have the line `<VirtualHost *:80> in your apache  config file. Then in your network configuration, list each of the 18 quintillion IPv6 addresses as individual interfaces in your system. Note that you'll likely need a few petabytes to store the network configuration file. You'll also need a massive kernel rewrite to allow for this many interfaces.

Comment: Also, make sure that nobody else is on the network with this address in use already or you'll get address conflicts. If you use `ping6 -c1` on each address you might finish checking the network before the universe ends.